# Cross compiling libSDL

Tags: linux, configure, compilation

I'm trying to cross-compile libSDL version 1.2 for a custom made, debian based Linux system. The toolchain I'm using is already configured properly so that I just run gcc/g++ on my the desired code and the resulting output is compatible with the target machine.

When I run `./configure --help` in the libSDL source directory, I see that I can basically just set some environment variables to point to my cross-compiler.

However, I also see the following options:

```
System types:
  --build=BUILD     configure for building on BUILD [guessed]
  --host=HOST       cross-compile to build programs to run on HOST [BUILD]
```

I looked into the `configure.in`, `build-scripts/config.sub`, and `build-scripts/config.guess` files but couldn't really figure out how it works.

Are these options required? If not, is it a good idea to use them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With autotools, `--build` is what you are building on and `--host` is what you want it to run on (there's also `--target`, but that's only important if what you're compiling is itself a compiler). Autotools will generally figure out `--build` on their own, so don't specify it if you don't have to (but look in `/usr/lib/gcc` to see what your compiler probably thinks `--build` should be)

So, eg, if you're building for i686 on x86_64, do

```
./configure --host=i686-linux-gnu
```

(And use the `-m32` options in CFLAGS, etc., but it sounds like you already have that ready.)

Whereas if you're building for x86_64 on i686, do

```
./configure --host=x86_64-linux-gnu
```

(You can build for all kinds of crazy hosts: rs6000-ibm-aix, sparc-sun-solaris, mips-idt-ecoff, etc..., assuming you have the appropriate gcc cross-compilers installed...)

GNU's page on it is here:

http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Cross_002dCompilation.html